# Azure - Kudu WebJob API being called several times per minute

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, kudu

I've uploaded a simple console application as a webjob to my Azure website. I have configured the website to log error pages (to LogFiles/DetailedErrors/). Several (3-6) times per minute I'm getting this error page logged:
[image]

It seems as though the Kudu WebJob API's GET for webjob history is being called, judging by the error page.

I don't know why this is happening. There is no "api" folder in Kudu/44.40324.1452, or in any other version of Kudu (there are like 7 of them).